# How can I force a mongodb error to test with jest the try and catch condition

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise, jestjs

I need to test a code but given the condition that my code is structured i can't make an error occurred and go to the catch condition.

That does not occur because my throw condition for the Promise. All is in another file that handles the returning of the promise

```
export const userExists = async (name, phone) => {
  try {
    const userExists = await Promise.all([User.findOne({ name}), User.findOne({ phone})]);
    if (userExists.some(el => !!el)) return true;
    else return false;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

Comment: What is it that you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want to enter in the catch condition for jest test purpose, but i can't seem to find a way

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your try block add:

`throw new Error("Test Error")`

Like so:

```
export const userExists = async (name, phone) => {
  try {
    throw new Error("Test Error");
    const userExists = await Promise.all([User.findOne({ name}), User.findOne({ phone})]);
    if (userExists.some(el => !!el)) return true;
    else return false;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```